# Put Labels with distances on lines

Tags: qgis, distance

this my first question in this forum and I don't have much experience on QGIS

I have a layer with lines representing streets in the city and I have to show the distances of intersection points of that line/street from the beginning of it

How can I do this?

Comment: is your distance an pre-calculated distance in an attribute? or do you want to generate this measurement on the fly?

Comment: I want to generate this measurement on the fly.